# Forward propagation slow - Training time normal

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm having trouble figuring out why when I perform forward propagation my code is extremely slow. The code in question can be found here: https://github.com/rekkit/lazy_programmer_ml_course/blob/develop/05_unsupervised_deep_learning/poetry_generator_rnn.py

I'm comparing the performance of my code to that of this: https://github.com/lazyprogrammer/machine_learning_examples/blob/master/rnn_class/srn_language_tf.py

The difference is when I run

```
self.session.run(self.predict(x_batch), feed_dict={...})
```

or when I run

```
self.returnPrediction(x_batch)
```

it takes about 0.14 seconds to run. Now this might not sound like a catastrophe, but that's 0.14 seconds per sentence (I'm making a RNN to predict the next word in a sentence). Since there are 1436 sentences, we're looking at about 3 minutes and 20 seconds per epoch. If I want to train 10 epochs, that's half an hour. Way more than the other code takes.

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem might be? The only difference that I can see is that I've modularized the code.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out. Every time I call the predict method I'm rebuilding the graph. Instead, in the fit method I define a variable:

```
preds = self.predict(self.tfX)
```

and then every time I need the predictions, instead of using:

```
predictions = self.session.run(self.predict(x_batch), feed_dict={...})
```

I use:

```
predictions = self.session.run(self.preds, feed_dict={...})
```